# Intercom over ethernet

Tags: ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

Can I use an ethernet cable to connect an intercom. I already have a used gigabit ethernet cable  to the specific rooms, so would like to know which two of the wires I could use.

Comment: I think this would depend on the specific intercom hardware you are using otherwise it's just going to be a guess for anyone answering I would think. Consider adding the make and model of the intercom hardware or system the Ethernet network will interface with potentially. Otherwise you are hardware shopping I think asking what hardware to buy to make non-Ethernet designed intercom system communicate with Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

The common gigabit Ethernet 1000BASE-T uses all four pairs. There are no spare pairs like with 100BASE-TX or 10BASE-T.

If you require full gigabit performance and low latency you need to run an additional cable. If you can live with some speed reduction and higher latency you can take a look at VDSL2 media converters.

There's also 1000BASE-T1 that only uses a single pair (with shorter reach). Possibly there are some converters for that as well.

Comment: Thanks all. I tried it and there was too much interference for the two intercom phones to work. I will have to run a separate wire.